# Is it needed to move the loss function and optimizer to GPU? (if I want to run my model training and testing throw gpu)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, model, loss-function

I'm building a simply Pytorch model which has just 1 hidden layer with 5 neurons and at first 2 entries variables. I have searching on Internet to build up the training (and testing) loop, and I have finally built something like this:

```
torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)

# Set the number of epochs
epochs = 100

# Put data to target device
X_train, y_train = X_train.to(device), y_train.to(device)
X_test, y_test = X_test.to(device), y_test.to(device)

# Build training and evaluation loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
  ### Training
  model_0.train()

  # 1. Forward pass
  y_logits = model_0(X_train).squeeze()
  y_pred = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(y_logits)) # turn logits -> pred probs -> pred labels

  # 2. Calculate loss/accuracy
  # loss = loss_fn(torch.sigmoid(y_logits), # nn.BCELoss expects prediction probabilities as input
  #                y_train)
  loss = loss_fn(y_logits, # nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss expects raw logits as input
                 y_train)
  acc = accuracy_fn(y_true=y_train,
                    y_pred=y_pred)

  # 3. Optimizer zero grad
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  # 4. Loss backward (backpropagation)
  loss.backward()

  # 5. Optimizer step (gradient descent)
  optimizer.step()

  ### Testing
  model_0.eval()
  with torch.inference_mode():
    # 1. Forward pass
    # 2. Calculate test loss/acc
    # ...
  
  if epoch % 10 == 0:
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch} | Loss: {loss:.5f}, Acc: {acc:.2f}% | Test loss: {test_loss:.5f}, Test acc: {test_acc:.2f}%")
```

My question now is as the training and testing data have been sent to GPU (to(device)) and my model (model_0) too:

```
# Let's replicate the model above using nn.Sequential()
model_0 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=5),
    nn.Linear(in_features=5, out_features=1)
).to(device)
```

Should I also send loss_fn (loss function) and optimizer to GPU, so that the entire training (and testing) process is done under it?

```
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() # BCEWithLogitsLoss = sigmoid activation function built-in

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=model_0.parameters(),
                            lr=0.1)
```